# CMake Path of a Config.cmake File

Tags: cmake

I'm working with CMake and want to ask if there is any command, that gives you the unknown path of a Config.cmake File. I need it, because the CMakeLists File should be designed for computers, where I don't know the structure of the folders (e.g. E:/exampleFolder/LibConfig.cmake). I have a library on the same partition like the CMakeLists File and want to know where exactly the LibaryConfig.cmake File is. Maybe the command findpackage(Libexample) could be expanded? I tried it with find_path() but how do I save or show the path?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand. How can a command give you something unknown? Do you want to find a file with a filename? To recursively scan all files to find a file that is named somehow? [`find_path` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) is not  small and rather exact - it says `cache entry named by <VAR> is created to store the result of this command.` Are some parts unclear to you? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi,exactly I only have the name of the file and want to get the path of it. I tried to save the path in a variable like set(path <VAR>) but unlikely 'path' is then just " ". So how can I output the value of the String 'VAR'?